# No compatible version found gulp when installing angular-multi-step-form

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp

This is what I enter in the terminal

```
sudo npm install --save-dev angular-multi-step-form
```

This is the error I get.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save-dev" "angular-multi-step-form"
npm ERR! node v5.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! No compatible version found: gulp@undefined
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 3.9.0, 3.8.11, 3.8.10, 3.8.9, 3.8.8, 3.8.7, 3.8.6, 3.8.5, 3.8.4, 3.8.3, 3.8.2, 3.8.1, 3.8.0, 3.7.0, 3.6.2, 3.6.1, 3.6.0, 3.5.6, 3.5.5, 3.5.2, 3.5.1, 3.5.0, 3.4.0, 3.3.4, 3.3.2, 3.3.1, 3.3.0, 3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.0.0, 2.7.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.0, 0.2.0, 0.1.0, 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I have gulp version 3.9.0. Tried to reinstalled npm and node.js. Deleted node_modules folder and then run npm install.

What can I do about it?

Thanks!